# Is there a way to invalidate a render array cache by somehow passing the user.data information to the cache context and tags?

Tags: caching, 9

Is there a way to invalidate a render array cache by somehow passing the user.data information to the cache context and tags?

Adding *user:ID* and *user* to the tags doesn't seem to invalidate when the user data is updated.

Comment: The cache tag `user:ID` only works for user fields, not user.data.

Comment: Sounds like a known issue? https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2477903